# Let $A$ be a connected subspace of $X$.If $A\subset B\subset \bar A$,then $B$ is also connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Hi i am reading Topology by Munkres and i have 2 doubt in the proof of **theorem 23.4**.The part that i have problem in is:

> $B$ cannot intersect D. This contradicts the fact $D$ is a nonempty subset of $B$.

My doubts are as follows:

1. Why $B$ cannot intersect $D$? That is how does $\bar C\cap D=\phi$ imply B cannot intersect D?
2. How does the statement "B cannot intersect D" contradicts the fact that $D$ is a nonempty subset of $B$?

For reference i am attaching the screenshot of the proof where i have highlighted the part.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: Note: "doubt" ≠ "question" in Am/Br English, and in no dialect of English can you "have a *doubt in* a proof".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $B \subset \bar A \subset \bar C$. Since $\bar C \cap D = \emptyset$, also $B \cap D = \emptyset$. But we assumed $B  = C \cup D$, thus $B \cap D = D$.